# Android Nougat: onHandleIntent called once

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, intentservice, android-7.0-nougat

Our application is starting an event to download an RSS feed and display media upon a button press.

The IntentService is being launched using the following code:

```
Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingMessageHandler());
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RssReaderIntentService.class);

intent.putExtra("Messenger", messenger);

startService(intent);
```

The IntentService is also in listed in the AndroidManifest.xml below:

```
<service android:name=".services.RssReaderIntentService" android:exported="false" />
```

And the onHandleIntent method is below:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent)
{
    LOGGER.trace("onHandleIntent");

    try {
        Messenger remoteMessenger = workIntent.getParcelableExtra("Messenger");
        if (bindData(remoteMessenger))
            readRss();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    stopSelf();
}
```

When the service runs for the first time it executes correctly and calls *onHandleIntent*, however, when the services goes to run again it never reaches *onHandleIntent.* The only method that is called is *onStartCommand.*

I was curious if this was due to a problem with Android Nougat vs Android KitKat (the application runs normally on KitKat). I did research on deprecations and any changes that could be there but I didn't find anything that could cause this issue.

**EDIT**
The app calls *onHandleIntent* correctly while debugging but not when the debugger is detached.

**EDIT #2**
We have three scenarios where the app is running differently.
 1. Device running kitkat with a slower processor than the other two devices, the app works perfectly and as intended.
 2. Device running nougat with a faster processor than the first device, the app runs the service only once when no debugger is attached but when a debugger is attached it continually runs the service.
 3. Device running nougat with the fastest processor out of the three only runs the service once regardless if a debugger is attached.

Comment: remove stopSelf

Comment: @greywolf82 I thought you were supposed to run stopSelf after your service was completed? Also, removing that line unfortunately did not fix the problem.

Comment: True but not for an intentservice

Comment: @greywolf82 do you know of anything else that could cause the IntentService not to call onHandleIntent? I've been researching this for a while now and can't find much of a solution.